# Tumblrブログのヘッダー画像を固定したい

Tags: html, 画像

http://omg165cm.tumblr.com/
上は私のブログです。

http://melmilkuoxou.tumblr.com/
のように上に画像をヘッダーを設定し固定したいです。

Answer (score 1):

header要素に`position: fixed;`を指定するとスクロールしてもヘッダーをウインドウに固定することができます。